# Docker storage setup utility absent in 1.11.x version

Tags: docker

I need to use `docker-storage-setup` command, which is absent in my current docker package 1.11.1, when I did a `yum provides` on the command name, it seems it was available in previous versions.

Why it is absent in the current release?

```
docker-1.6.2-14.el7.centos.x86_64 : Automates deployment of containerized applications
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/docker-storage-setup



docker-1.7.1-108.el7.centos.x86_64 : Automates deployment of containerized applications
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/docker-storage-setup



docker-1.7.1-115.el7.x86_64 : Automates deployment of containerized applications
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/docker-storage-setup



docker-1.8.2-7.el7.centos.x86_64 : Automates deployment of containerized applications
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/docker-storage-setup



docker-1.8.2-8.el7.centos.x86_64 : Automates deployment of containerized applications
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/docker-storage-setup



docker-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64 : Automates deployment of containerized applications
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/docker-storage-setup



docker-1.9.1-25.el7.centos.x86_64 : Automates deployment of containerized applications
Repo        : extras
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/docker-storage-setup
```

Comment: It might have changed packages or something. Have you already done a `yum whatprovides */docker-storage-setup` ?

Comment: Yes , you can see the output of that in my question detail.

Comment: I think there might be some major change in current release and they may have replaced it with something else.